# matching with prefix and suffix words in a list and returning a string with all the words linked

Tags: python, list, match, prefix, suffix

I have a list of words, I have to match all words in this list with the same prefix and suffix. my function will return a string with all words linked. there is only one way to link all words

```
list_ = ["sequence","horse", "ermin"]
```

Desired output:

```
"horsequencermin"
```

how can I get the desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to join them? If so try `"".join(list)`

Comment: join method doesn't match the same prefix and suffix, but joins together all the words in their irder in the list. I need a way to control the equal prefix and suffix

Comment: are you trying to remove duplicate letters at start/end when joining?

Comment: the problem is before joining, when i search the correct word to join, i have to check if a word has a prefix that can be joined with the suffix of the previous word,   the result will be only horSEquencErmin. but how can i find two words to join together? probably i could have used a list which matches all the possibilities also whit less word as expected, and at the end, i could have the longest. i need only the function which matches all the combinations

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your list to join

```
def join(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        print(list[0])
        return True;
    one = list[0];
    for x in range(1,len(list)):
        two = list[x]
        three = overlap(one, two)
        if(len(three) != 0):
            temp = list[:]
            temp.append(three)
            temp.remove(one)
            temp.remove(two)
            if(join(temp)):
                return True;

    return False


def overlap(one , two):
    len1 = len(one)
    len2 = len(two)

    for i in range(1,min(len1,len2)+1):
        subone = one[len1-i:]
        subone2 = one[:i]
        subtwo = two[:i]
        subtwo2 = two[len2-i:]
        if(subone == subtwo):
            return one[:len1-i]+subone+two[i:]
        if(subone2 == subtwo2):
            return two[:len2-i]+subone2+one[i:]

    return ""
```